# When creating a sparse matrix out of a dense np.ndarry in Python, why does the number of bytes show up as 48 bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sparse-matrix

I am currently doing research in scientific computing. I work in Python with pretty large dense matrices. For example, to solve a single problem, I may have to create upwards of 60 different dense matrices of size 60,000 x 60,000 entries. Only 60,000 entries of each matrix (the diagonal of each matrix) is zero. Each entry is of type np.complex128.

Because I am running into memory problems (PC only has 16 GB of RAM), I decided to see if sparse matrices would help. I thought because it was so dense, it wouldn't reduce the size of the matrix (in terms of memory usage). However, it seems as though it does.

For example, if I run the following on a Jupyter Notebook on VSCode:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
import sys

n = 1000
A = np.random.uniform(1.0, 10.0, size=(n, n)) + 1j*np.random.uniform(1.0, 10.0, size=(n, n))
np.fill_diagonal(A, 0)
C = csc_matrix(A)

print(sys.getsizeof(A))
print(sys.getsizeof(C))
```

I get:

```
16000128
48
```

If I inspect C, I get the following output:

```
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.complex128'>' with 999000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

This is as we expect. If I then increase the size of `n`, the size of C remains the same at 48, but the size of A continually increases as one expects. This remains the same if I run the script on the command line as well. I am confused as to why the matrix remains at 48 bytes.

To ensure the sparse matrix matrix was actually giving me the same values as the dense matrix and not just creating an empty sparse matrix, I ran the following code:

```
truthvals = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        truthvals.append(A[i,j]==C[i,j])

print(np.array(truthvals).all())
```

This returned True, meaning all values of A and C are the same.

Can anyone explain why the sparse matrix is showing a value of 48 bytes for a dense matrix?

Comment: `C` is just a handle.  the package doesn't expose the size of the internal data structure to Python.

Comment: `getsizeof` gets close to the `nbytes` of a numpy `ndarray` (provided it isn't a `view`).  But we've seen a number of posts where people complain that it doesn't help with lists.  And I'm not surprised that it doesn't help with sparse, since the data is actually stored in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the python container is 48 bytes. Pointers are small. What you really want to know is how big the arrays are that are backing `A` and `C`. Numpy arrays have an `nbytes` property that will give you the size of the underlying array data structure in bytes.

```
>>> print(A.nbytes)

16000000
```

The CSR matrix format has three arrays that hold values, `data`, `indices`, and `indptr`.

```
>>> print(C.data.nbytes + C.indices.nbytes + C.indptr.nbytes)

19984004
```

CSR matrices are not a good data structure for non-sparse data.